# Problems with grunt - Warning: Task "ngAnnotate:dist" failed. Use --force to continue

Tags: javascript, npm, gruntjs, ng-annotate

I'm having issues with a Grunt task that was running fine before. I'm not sure why this is happening now. Here's the error:

```
Running "ngAnnotate:dist" (ngAnnotate) task
Generating ".tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js" from: ".tmp/concat/scripts/scripts.js"...ERROR
>> error: couldn't process source due to parse error
>> Assigning to rvalue (8818:4)
Warning: Task "ngAnnotate:dist" failed. Use --force to continue.
Error: Task "ngAnnotate:dist" failed.
at Task.<anonymous> (/home/hakan/webCondecca/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:205:15)
at Task.runTaskFn (/home/hakan/webCondecca/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:254:9)
at Task.<anonymous> (/home/hakan/webCondecca/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:300:12)
at /home/hakan/webCondecca/node_modules/grunt/lib/util/task.js:227:11
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I'm not too familiar with Grunt and this is the first project I've actually used it in. I'd love to get some help. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You may have javascript code in your html file, i men like this see the picture [erro ng-annotate grunt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHrIO.png)